# ECS Deploy Github Actions ennable execute command

Tags: amazon-web-services, github-actions, amazon-ecs

I need to ennable execute command in a deployment do it with [AWS-ACTIONS](https://github.com/aws-actions/amazon-ecs-deploy-task-definition) but I don't found the way to ennable it. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you already have an OIDC role setup in AWS for use in actions? If not, see this doc https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/security-hardening-your-deployments/configuring-openid-connect-in-amazon-web-services